# Учусь програмировать и пишу игру про корабль с пришельцами 2D из книги Прискоренный курс по питону Ерик маттес

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, pygame

```
import sys
import pygame


class AlienInvasion:
    '''Загальний класс, що керує ресурсами та поведінкою гри'''

    def __init__(sekf):
        '''Ініціалізувати гру, створити ресурси гри'''
        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption("AlienInvasion")
        #Колір фону
        bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    def run_game(self):
        '''Розпочати цикл гри'''
        while True:
            #СЛідкувати за подіями калавіатури та миші
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
            
                #Наново перемалювати екран на кожній ітерації циклу
                self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)


                #Останній намальований екран показати
                pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Створити екземпляр гри та запустити.
    al = AlienInvasion()
    al.run_game()
```

---

Получаю  ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\pygame\alien_invasion.py", line 36, in 
> al = AlienInvasion()
> File "D:\pygame\alien_invasion.py", line 12, in **init**
> self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
> NameError: name 'self' is not defined. Did you mean: 'sekf'?

---

```
import sys
import pygame

class AlienInvasion:
    '''Загальний класс, що керує ресурсами та поведінкою гри'''

    def __init__(sekf):
        '''Ініціалізувати гру, створити ресурси гри'''
        pygame.init()

        sekf.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption("AlienInvasion")
        #Колір фону
        bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    def run_game(self):
        '''Розпочати цикл гри'''
        while True:
            #СЛідкувати за подіями калавіатури та миші
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
            
                #Наново перемалювати екран на кожній ітерації циклу
                self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)


                #Останній намальований екран показати
                pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Створити екземпляр гри та запустити.
    al = AlienInvasion()
    al.run_game()
```

Получаю  ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\pygame\alien_invasion.py", line 37, in 
> al.run_game()
> File "D:\pygame\alien_invasion.py", line 28, in run_game
> self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
> AttributeError: 'AlienInvasion' object has no attribute 'settings'

Comment: Ну молодец, пиши игру.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import pygame


class AlienInvasion:
    '''Загальний класс, що керує ресурсами та поведінкою гри'''

#   def __init__(sekf):
# -------------> ^^v^ <----------------------------------------------      self
    def __init__(self):
        '''Ініціалізувати гру, створити ресурси гри'''
        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))
        pygame.display.set_caption("AlienInvasion")

        #Колір фону
#        bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        self.bg_color = (230, 130, 130)                                   # +++ self.

    def run_game(self):
        '''Розпочати цикл гри'''
        while True:
            #СЛідкувати за подіями калавіатури та миші
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
            
                #Наново перемалювати екран на кожній ітерації циклу
#                self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
                self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)                         # +++ self.bg_color

                #Останній намальований екран показати
                pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Створити екземпляр гри та запустити.
    al = AlienInvasion()
    al.run_game()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @reactionreaction что не так?